# find last occurrence and prepend using sed

Tags: bash, sed

How can I find the last occurrence and prepend data?  I tried the `\1` at the end of the `sed` command see code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

var_function_name="func_1"
var_js_code=$(printf '%s' "<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n'"<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n'"<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n')
var_insert_js_code=$(echo "$var_js_code" |sed 's|\(</script>\)|var result = '"$var_function_name"'();\nalert(result)\n\1|') 

echo "$var_insert_js_code"
```

Produces:

```
<script>
var result = func_1();
alert(result)
</script>
<script>
var result = func_1();
alert(result)
</script>
<script>
var result = func_1();
alert(result)
</script>
```

I'm trying to just insert code before the last `</script>` tag only.  To see what I'm trying to get look below.  **Please note I won't know how many `</script>` tags there will be hence I'm just looking to work on the last one found.**

```
<script>
</script>
<script>
</script>
<script>
var result = func_1();
alert(result)
</script>
```

Comment: To prepend text to the last match in the file you can exchange the pattern and hold space as explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162377/sed-remove-the-very-last-occurrence-of-a-string-a-comma-in-a-file

Comment: You really overcomplicated a simple question. If the question is about `sed`, write out what the input and desired output are. Period. No need to include a `bash` script that does other stuff not related to the question.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I've been told to give fully working code that shows exactly what you are trying to do.  I'm using bash using variables using sed hence the bash code with variables with sed code.

Comment: Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) carefully. To give you an example, defining `var_function_name="func_1"` and then using `$var_function_name` somewhere is completely **not** relevant to the question. You can (and should) just put `func_1` where it's needed. Besides, crafting a MWE can help you, by itself, discover bugs in your code.

Comment: @sergio I clicked on that link about `remove the very last occurrence of a string`, but when I did a search about `hold space` as you stated nothing was found.

Comment: @RickT that link contains an example like this: `sed 'x;${s:</script>\|$:xyz&:;p;x;};1d' input`. The hold space is explained in [sed's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: [sed The Hold Buffer](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-52). But.. can't you just modify the `printf`? This should work: `printf '%s' "<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n'"<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n'"<script>"$'\n'"$var_js_code</script>"$'\n'`

Comment: @KamilCuk I put a note in `Bold` saying I won't know how many `</script>` tags there will be hence wanting to get / work with just the last occurrence using sed

Comment: But does it have to be sed? Do you have GNU sed? Just `tac | sed -z 's@</script>@&\nsomething@' | tac`? @edit: not `rev`, it's `tac`, sry. It is REALLY hard to do in sed, use other tools. Rule of a thumb - if you have to have a context of more then one line, don't use sed.

Comment: @KamilCuk It's Ubuntu 18.04 ( I guess it's GNU sed) what other tools do you suggest?  I didn't know getting the last occurrence of a pattern using sed was so difficult.

Comment: I suggest `awk`. Or I suggest the pipe that I written for you above.

Comment: I suggest using a language with a proper XML/HTML library, rather than trying to use tools that aren't designed for such a structured language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little trick:

```
tac | sed -z 's@</script>@&\nsomething@' | tac
```

Because `sed` works on first occurence, to get the last occurence you can:

- `tac` - reverse the lines
- `sed -z` - parse the stream as zero separated
  and then
- `tac` reverse the lines again.

Also `&` in replacement pattern in `sed` means the whole matched pattern. So the whole `</script>` in your case.

Ta da:

```
var_function_name="func_1"
var_js_code=$(printf '%s' "<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n'"<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n'"<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n')
var_insert_js_code=$(echo "$var_js_code" | tac | sed -z 's|</script>|&\nvar result = '"$var_function_name"'();\nalert(result)|' | tac) 

echo "$var_insert_js_code"
```

In `sed` you can hold all the lines up until the pattern and print the last lines when pattern occurs and on the last line prepend the data:

```
sed -n '
  \@</script>@{
    x
    s/^\n//
    p
    s/.*//
    x
  }
  ${
    H;x
    s/^/var result = '"$var_function_name"'();\nalert(result)/
    p
    q
  }
  H
'
```

and:

```
var_function_name="func_1"
var_js_code=$(printf '%s' "<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n'"<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n'"<script>"$'\n'"</script>"$'\n')
var_insert_js_code=$(echo "$var_js_code" | sed -n '\@</script>@{x;s/^\n//;p;s/.*//;x};${H;x;s/^/var result = '"$var_function_name"'();\nalert(result)/;p;q};H;$b')
```

echo "$var_insert_js_code"

Comment: Or `sed -rz 's@(.*)(</script>)@\1\nsomething\2@'` without `tac`.